# How to run a Clojure app with command line parameters

Tags: clojure, command-line-arguments

To run Clojure files from command line, I'm using a zhs alias I added to my .zshrc:

```
alias 'clojure=java -cp /home/sinan/cclojure/lib/clojure-1.2.1.jar:/home/sinan/cclojure/lib/clojure-contrib-1.2.0.jar clojure.main -i '
```

With this, I can run my Clojure app like this:

```
clojure test3.clj
```

But  it doesn't work when I want to send command line parameters.

```
➜  src  clojure test3.clj arg1 arg2
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: arg1 (No such file or directory)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:120)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:79)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.loadFile(Compiler.java:5817)
        at clojure.main$load_script.invoke(main.clj:221)
        at clojure.main$script_opt.invoke(main.clj:273)
        at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:354)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:457)
        at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:377)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:172)
        at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:482)
        at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
```

What am I doing wrong? Is my way of running Clojure apps wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you just need to specify name of script, without `-i` key after `clojure.main`. In your case, `clojure.main` thinks, that test.clj is program to eval before (and it do it), while `arg1` is script to execute

See description of option for [clojure.main/main](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.main-api.html#clojure.main/main) function